# return string from function objective c

Tags: objective-c, xml

I have this function that will get xml through a request operation:

```
-(id)xmlRequest:(NSString *)xmlurl
{
    AFKissXMLRequestOperation *operation = [AFKissXMLRequestOperation XMLDocumentRequestOperationWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:xmlurl]] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, DDXMLDocument *XMLDocument) {
        NSLog(@"XMLDocument: %@", XMLDocument);
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, DDXMLDocument *XMLDocument) {
        NSLog(@"Failure!");
    }];
    [operation start];
    return operation;
}
```

This is my code that calls this function:

```
Request *http=[[Request alloc] init];
NSString *data=[http xmlRequest:@"http://legalindexes.indoff.com/sitemap.xml"];
NSError *error;
DDXMLDocument *ddDoc=[[DDXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:data options:0 error:&error];
NSArray *xmlItems=[ddDoc nodesForXPath:@"//url" error:&error];
NSMutableArray *returnArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[xmlItems count]];
for(DDXMLElement* itemElement in xmlItems){
    DDXMLElement *element = [[itemElement nodesForXPath:@"loc" error:&error] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"valueasstring %@", element);
    [returnArray addObject:element];
}
```

I need the xmlRequest to return a string so I can get the XML but the [operation start] creates correct output but I can't put it in a string.  How can I direct the output into a string?

Comment: Have you tried `return [operation start];`?

Comment: (I haven't a clue what AFKissXMLRequestOperation is or what the `operation` method on it does.)

Comment: OK, it's a subclass of NSOperation.  So you're starting an NSOperation, and there's no way, synchronously, to get the result of that asynchronous operation.  You need to monitor for the operation to complete and then fetch the result, outside of this routine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that code, the network request happens asynchronously – there’s no way for you to return its result from that method.

The line `NSLog(@"XMLDocument: %@", XMLDocument);` is inside the success handler block – that will be called when the request actually finishes. You should replace the log statement with code to save your string somewhere, and only then call the remainder of your code.

There’s a few ways you could do this:

1. Create a property on the class like `@property (strong) DDXMLDocument *XMLDocument;`

   You can then replace the log statement with `self.XMLDocument = XMLDocument;`

   Then, make another method that does the rest of your processing.
2. Alternatively, just make another method like `-processWithXMLDocument:(DDXMLDocument *)XMLDocument;` that you can call from the block, simply passing it as an argument.

   I can’t remember what dispatch queue the success handler will be called on, so you may have to be careful to run your code back on the main thread `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){…`

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.  I believe this will work, I'm just not sure how to do it.  I try to set the XMLDocument equal to a variable but I can't return anything in the success block and it doesn't recognize the variable outside the success block.